# Run two processes with two threads C++ wait function

Tags: c++, multithreading, wait

I have a problem with thread handling.

I want this two threads to run in the background:

```
if(jobdone==true){
        jobdone=false;
        c=' ';
        can1=qu.at(0);
        qu.erase(qu.begin());
        cout<<"ID: "<<can1.id<<endl;
        cout<<"Time: "<<can1.tiempo<<endl;
        cout<<"Type "<<can1.type[can1.id_type]<<endl;
        Hilo h(&can1);
        thread x(h);
        x.detach();
    }
    if(jobdone2==true){
        jobdone2=false;
        c=' ';
        can2=qu.at(0);
        qu.erase(qu.begin());
        cout<<"ID: "<<can2.id<<endl;
        cout<<"Time: "<<can2.tiempo<<endl;
        cout<<"Type "<<can2.type[can1.id_type]<<endl;
        Hilo2 h2(&can2);
        thread y(h2);
        y.detach();
    }
```

As soon as each of them finishes, their respective flag "jobdone" would get activated so I can start with a new thread, in a few words, I want to run every process of a Queue with two Threads.

Each thread runs a "wait" function that keep it running until the time that each object has, finishes, and then activates the flag;

Everything runs smoothly with one thread but when I use both threads it gets looped in the wait function.

This is the wait function:

```
char wait(Canica &can)
{
   char c;
   cout<<endl;
   clock_t endwait;
   endwait= clock() + (can.tiempo+4) *CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
   while(clock()<endwait  && c!='s' && c!='e' && c!='b'){
       c=' ';
       can.elapsed_time=int((endwait-clock())/1000000);
       if(kbhit())c=getchar();
   }
   if(c=='b'|| c=='e')
       can.res_time=int((endwait-clock())/1000000);
   cout<<"FINISH"<<endl;
   return c;
```

}

I've already tried making two separate "wait" functions, one for each thread but it doesn't work.

Here's the code of the threads, both are the same, just the name changes.

```
class Hilo{
public:
void  print();
char c;
Canica *can;
Hilo(Canica *c) { can=c; }

void operator()()
{

    c=waitH1(*can);
    cout<<endl;
    if(c=='e'){
        cout<<"Error de canica"<<endl;
        can->error=true;
    }
    if(c=='s')
    {

        can->exit_flag=1;
        {
            jobdone = true;
        }
    }else{
        if(c=='b')
        {
            can->blocked_flag=1;
            can->pushBlocked(*can);

        }
        else{
            {
                jobdone = true;
            }
            can->ejecutado=true;
        }

    }



}
```

};

Comment: I don't quite get what you're trying to do with the code, but... You need to take a look at events/signals, because that's the way synchronizing multiple threads works. This will depend on the end on the OS you are using, but you can probably use an abstraction layer in some library (boost has one, IIRC). If you are in Windows then take a look into the 'WaitForMultipleObjects' API function: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687025(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @RodrigoGómez What I'm trying to do is to execute a whole list of objects with two threads in parallel, each thread has to wait for X amount of seconds. The problem is that the "wait" function I use get cycled when I try to run both threads in parallel. I've already tried using the signals you are talking about, but that's doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: Your wait function is never going to work when running more than one thread. I would venture it would never run even when running just one thread, as long as the thread is not the main one. You are using user input in that function, that doesn't make sense except if your thread is the main one. Actually, your thread code is also using the interface, which you can't do like that. You need to synchronize your output with the main thread, never handle it directly in the thread code. And for that you need signals/events too.

Comment: It is a waste to use two separate threads for cycling in wait. It's better to make array/list of events to wait, sort them by ending time and wait for first one, signal, wait for next etc.

Also you have uninitialized char in wait function. In release build it'll have random value and could prevent cycle from running at all.